# How to remove white space below the drawing inside the cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  twoside]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,asymmetric,
top=3.5cm,left=2cm,right=1.8cm,bottom=1cm,
headsep=0pt,footskip=0pt,
headheight=200pt}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Edit Commands
\def\arraystretch{1} % Row
\def\bigskip{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % Column
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{#1}}
\newcommand{\arr}[2]{\definecolor{color}{RGB}{#1}\tikz{\path[draw=color, line width=1mm, line join=round, line cap=round, -{Straight Barb[scale=1.5, line join=round, line cap=round]},rotate=#2-45] (0,0) -- (0.7,0.7);}}
\newcommand{\zero}{\centerline{\tikz{\node[circle, fill=gray, minimum size=0.4\linewidth] {};}}}
\newcommand{\goal}[1]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,valign=t]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.99\linewidth}{|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
\zero & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} & \arr{84,130,53}{90} &  \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good evening!
You could just change the `arraystretch` variable. In your case, add this line of command just before your `minipage` environment:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
```

Here's the full document:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  twoside]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,asymmetric,
top=3.5cm,left=2cm,right=1.8cm,bottom=1cm,
headsep=0pt,footskip=0pt,
headheight=200pt}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Edit Commands
\def\arraystretch{1} % Row
\def\bigskip{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % Column
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{#1}}
\newcommand{\arr}[2]{\definecolor{color}{RGB}{#1}\tikz{\path[draw=color, line width=1mm, line join=round, line cap=round, -{Straight Barb[scale=1.5, line join=round, line cap=round]},rotate=#2-45] (0,0) -- (0.7,0.7);}}
\newcommand{\zero}{\centerline{\tikz{\node[circle, fill=gray, minimum size=0.4\linewidth] {};}}}
\newcommand{\goal}[1]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,valign=t]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.99\linewidth}{|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
\zero & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} & \arr{84,130,53}{90} &  \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you pelase check this code and there is a still space
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.99\linewidth}{|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
\zero & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} & \arr{84,130,53}{90} &  \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} \\
\hline
\arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} & \arr{84,130,53}{90} &  \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}