# How to remove white space below the drawing inside the tabular cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,asymmetric,
top=3.5cm,left=2cm,right=1.8cm,bottom=1cm,
headsep=0pt,footskip=0pt,
headheight=200pt}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Edit Commands
\def\arraystretch{0} % Row
\def\bigskip{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % Column
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{#1}}
\newcommand{\arr}[2]{\definecolor{color}{RGB}{#1}\tikz{\path[draw=color, line width=1mm, line join=round, line cap=round, -{Straight Barb[scale=1.5, line join=round, line cap=round]},rotate=#2-45] (0,0) -- (0.7,0.7);}}
\newcommand{\zero}{\centerline{\tikz{\node[circle, fill=gray, minimum size=0.4\linewidth] {};}}}
\newcommand{\goal}[1]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,valign=t]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth} 
    \centering 
    \begin{tabularx}{0.99\linewidth}{|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}} 
        \hline \zero & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} & \arr{84,130,53}{90} & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} \\ 
        \hline \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} & \arr{84,130,53}{90} & \arr{234,107,20}{0} & \arr{191,143,0}{45} \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\arraystretch{0} % Row` will destroy all vertical spacing of latex arrays and tables, whatever the intention of that is, you probably did not mean this definition.

Comment: Also note the warning Package Fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (0.0pt): 
Make it at least 4.35004pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

Comment: if you delete `\centerline` (which isn't really a latex command) from`\zero` then the first row is more compact.

Comment: I edited footskip=5pt and i deleted \centerline, I got the zero not vertically centered. I want to edit the zero command not the tabular arguments

Comment: No, please do not edit the question like that!!! You have edited in most of the answer into the question so now your example does not show any white space so no one can post an answer telling you how to remove white space.

Comment: I am sorry i am not familiar with the procedures.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `\def\arraystretch{0}` aparently originated from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575848/134144) to one of OP's previous question.

Comment: @leandriis hmm OK actually if the tables are just symbolic boxes losing baseline spacing is possibly Ok as long as it is only done very locally. It is pretty weird though:-)